Questions regarding $C_n^1(\overline\Omega)$, the space of functions with normal derivatives
The definition of which functions have normal derivatives, and to which we can apply Green's First Identity to, seems to be very delicate. Let $\Omega$ be a $C^1$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with $d\geq 2$, let $n$ be the outward pointing normal vector on $\Gamma=\partial\Omega$. and let $u\in C^1(\Omega)$. The following is from R. Dautray and J.-L. Lions. Mathematical analysis and numerical methods for science and technology. Volume 1: Physical origins and classical methods. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1990. Chapter II Section 1.3b, page 229
"
... $\partial u/\partial n$ is defined by
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}(a) = \lim_{\substack{x\to a,\, x\in \Gamma\\t\to 0,\, t>0}}\operatorname{grad} u(x-tn(a))\cdot n(x)$$
... We shall use the notation $\mathscr{C}_n^1(\overline\Omega)$ to denote the class of functions with $\partial u/\partial n$ defined on $\Gamma$."
The aim here is to define a class of functions, larger than $C^1(\overline\Omega)$ such that Green's Identities and other formulae still apply, and in which we may search for solutions of the Neumann problem. My main question is whether this definition is equivalent to another space, $C_\nu(\Omega)$ this time from G. B. Folland. Real analysis. Modern techniques and their applications. Pure Appl. Math., Wiley, New York, NY, 2nd ed., 1999. Chapter 3, Section A, page 116. He denotes the normal by $\nu$ and boundary by $S$.
"We define $C_\nu(\Omega)$ to be the space of functions $u\in C^1(\Omega)\cap C(\overline\Omega)$ such that the limit
$$\partial_{\nu^-} u(x) = \lim_{t<0,\, t\to 0} \nu(x)\cdot \nabla u(x+t\nu(x))$$
exists for each $x\in S$, the convergence being uniform on $S$."
It is shown in Dautray and Lions that functions in $C_n^1(\overline\Omega)$ are in $C(\overline\Omega)$ and that the (more complicated) limit involving $x$ and $t$ converges uniformly with respect to $a\in \Gamma$, so we have $ C_n^1(\overline{\Omega} )\subseteq C_\nu(\Omega)$, however I have been unable to prove the opposite direction without assuming that $\nabla u$ is bounded. Folland mentions that Green's Identity applies to functions in $C_\nu(\Omega)$ on page 118 and says that "the definitions of $\partial_{\nu^-}$ and $\partial_{\nu^+}$ are designed precisely to make this argument work" ($\partial_{\nu^+}$ is the normal derivative from the outside of $\Omega$, I skipped this to not over-complicate things further). Moreover, the proof outline that he gives seems to match the proof outline given on page 230 of Dautray and Lions. This is why I suspect the spaces could be equal.
I think the key to the above problem could be related to som unproved results in the same section (II.1.3b) of Dautray-Lions, which I have had no luck proving. Here we have a slightly more general setup. Let $p$ be a continuous field on $\Omega$ (I believe this means a continuous function $p:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$) and say that a vector $e\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is leaving $\Omega$ at $a\in \Gamma$ if $\cos(e,n(a))>0$.
Lemma 2. If the limit
$$\lim_{\substack{x\to a, \, x\in \Gamma\\ t\to 0,\,t>0}}p(x-te)\cdot n(x)$$
exists for at least one unit vector $e$ leaving $\Omega$ at $a$, then it exists for all such vectors. More precisely, being given a compact set $K$ of $\Gamma$ such that for all $a\in K$ the above limit exists for at least one unit vector $e$ leaving $\Omega$ at $a$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ , the above limit exists uniformly for $a\in K$ and $e$ a unit vector satisfying $\cos(e,n(a))\geq \epsilon$.
I am especially interested in the existence of the limit uniformly, but I am also unable to prove the first part of the Lemma. Any attempt I have made to prove these usually stops when I can't assume that $p$ is bounded. I also haven't been able to prove the next result (Proposition 3).
Any help or other references would be greatly appreciated.
